# How do I store css rules in database in drupal?

Tags: css, database, drupal

I want to store my css rules in database to allow users to apply their own css on a page. I need help with it. I am facing issue with curly braces.

Comment: That sounds like it could become a bit of a nightmare to manage the css going forward. Why not just store class names and keep the css styles in the css doc?

Comment: I want users to apply their custom css on individual pages so want to store that in database and load for a particular page for a particular user. User have a field to enter their css rules to go in db.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. What sort of database and what are the field settings? Are you using any functions on your insert like `mysql_real_escape_string()`?

Comment: I am using drupal 7, mysql.  I have used escape function but not working

Comment: You could just install [CSS injector](http://drupal.org/project/css_injector) and give your users permissions to add rules to that

Comment: Using [skinr](http://drupal.org/project/skinr) is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

you can [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the css and store it and while retriving you can [un-serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) them while fetching back . You can also use modules like [css Injector](http://drupal.org/project/css_injector), if it satisfies your needs

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 6:

Add a CCK field to the node. Use a text field, multiple lines. Hide the field from being outputted, using CCK's feature for doing this. Now you have a field for people to type CSS into, but no way to output it.

So then edit your theme's node.tpl.php and add something like this

`<?php echo "<style type='text/css'>" . $node->field_fieldname[0]['value'] . "</style>"; ?>` where field_fieldname is the name of your new field.

In Drupal 7: similar, but use the core Fields module to do the same thing instead of CCK.

Comment: Also: having users type in CSS like this is a bad idea and will result in problems and/or a web site that looks terrible.

Comment: Hi 

Actually site admin while adding content may change the look of the content by adding custom css. I am adding custom fields using form API in drupal 7. Big sites like resumator.com are using this feature.